# Simple file version control module for .NET Web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a Web app that allows a user to upload and store files; however I'd like to add a simple version history feature to the files they upload based on the file name.

Is there an existing framework/module I can integrate for the version history part or is it better for me to write it up myself? I feel like there could be a lot of plumbing that's already been done in a framework. I couldn't find any and most of my Google searches turned up actual project version control software.

I'm looking at using .NET and C# to make this Web app.

Comment: what would be the point of versioning? just a log? ability to rollback? diffing two versions? something else?

Comment: For rolling back basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any libraries off the top of my head, but this is something I would probably roll myself anyway. The solution is simple. Take a SHA-1 (or other appropriate) hash of the file bytes, and use that as the filename/primary key in your backing store for that version of the file. This is called 'content-addressable', and is a simplified version of what git does.

One possible benefit of this is that if 2 users upload identical versions of a file, you only have to store it once.

Then you just need an list somewhere that tracks which hashes go in which order for a given user filename.

**EDIT:**

Its also worth noting that if you were not dealing with blobs, but structured data or your app objects, you might get much of this functionality from your data store via SQL triggers, or the RavenDB versioning bundle, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a version control system, like Subversion. This will be really reliable, easily integrable, it will offer history (with great details) and capability to download any of the past versions. Bonus: you can even diff two versions (obviously this make sense only for text based file types).